# How to Feature file keywords are wired to java Code in Karate?

Tags: testing, karate, web-api-testing

I have recently started using Karate frame work for my API tests cases. It was great. But I was wondering how the feature files are getting parsed ? How to wiring is done in Karate ?

```
* def handler = function(msg){ return msg.startsWith('hello') }
* def socket = karate.webSocket(demoBaseUrl + '/websocket', handler)
* socket.send('Billie')
* def result = socket.listen(5000)
* match result == 'hello Billie !'
```

In the above code.. "Karate.websocket" is calling which method in framework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate uses a JVM-based JavaScript engine that makes calling any Java code on the class-path very easy.

To answer your question, the `webSocket()` method is in the [`ScenarioBridge`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/v1.0.1/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/core/ScenarioBridge.java#L852) class. This class is injected into the feature file with the name `karate` at run-time.